# How to avoid a runtime error where a string is inputted into a .nextInt();?

Tags: java, string, runtime-error

How to avoid a runtime error where a string is inputted into a `.nextInt();`?
I'm trying to do user input. Say they were to enter a letter by accident where a number is required, it will just show a runtime error.  How do I make it so more inputs pop up until a number is inputted?

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

int num1;
System.out.println("Please enter an interger number:);
num1 = userInput.nextInt();
```

When the box pops up for the user to enter an interger they input a string and get a runtime error. How do I avoid this error?

An input that would create this error would be any letter.

I am using DrJava on Eclipse.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. What programming language are you using? Can you post some of your actual code? Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some pointers.

Comment: @BM5k above is that enough?? let me know first time using stack overflow sorry for wrong question format?

Comment: no problem, it can take a while to get used to the posting rules & guidelines :) Your question is getting better, but please also include an example of input that causes the error with the entire error message. That will help other people find AND hopefully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hasNextInt() method, so something like

```
if (userInput.hasNextInt()){ //do Something.. }
```

Or take any input as a string, then parse that as an Integer, and do a try catch to find errors.